# passing integer Argument in a function

Tags: swift, func

```
func getDriverFromId(var id : Int?) -> String {

    if id == nil {
        return "No Driver Assigned"
    }
    else {
        loadDriversREST()
    }

    return "test"

}

getDriverFromId(nil)
```

I am getting an error "`getDriverFromID` with an argument list of type (nil)"

Comment: I've copied the code you have supplied into a project and it compiles without error. Have you included all the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually correct and works fine. That said I have a couple of suggestions and have included a (working) playground for you.

Given that your code first checks whether the ID is nil, you don't actually need the else as the flow would stop (or return) anyway - this makes it a little more pleasing to the eye...

With this in mind, your function would look like this:

```
func getDriverFromId(var id : Int?) -> String {

    if id == nil {
        return "No Driver Assigned"
    }

    loadDriversREST()

    return "test"

}
```

Also, unless you plan on changing "id" from within the code of the function, then you don't need var before it. Basically, function arguments are non-mutable by default so you can't change them, adding var enables you to change the value of the argument within the code.

With all of this in mind, here is a playground showing everything working. Hope this helped...

```
import UIKit

func loadDriversREST() {
    // doesn't actually do anything
    return
}

func getDriverFromId(id : Int?) -> String {

    if id == nil {
        return "No Driver Assigned"
    }


    loadDriversREST()

    return "test"

}

println(getDriverFromId(nil))   // this works
println(getDriverFromId(15))    // this works
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
func getDriveFromId(var id: Int?) -> String {

if id == nil {

    return "No Driver Assigned"

} else {

    //Your func
    return "test"
}

}
```

Comment: The return being (or not being) nested in the if/else is not an issue. The use of `var` in the parameter list is legal, it [allows that parameter to be changed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID172), but this is probably not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Do you have anything else going on? I put it all in a playground and it's fine, Steve Wiflord is correct if you want to change the value of the parameter inside the function you can use var. I would always still suggest though to return inside of your scope, though that shouldn't be the reason why you're not seeing a result because the nil return happens first.